# Unity Gradle Build failed while trying to build project as an APK (2019)

Tags: unity-game-engine, build, sdk, apk, build-error

I have a really big problem. I wasted many hours with trying to build a little game i made as an APK. I switched the build platform to android, installed the JDK, NDK and SDK tools and it should work. But at the moment when unity is "Building Gradle Prject" an error is poping up: **1 exception was raised by workers: See the console for details.**

And then there are 60 Errors in the console.

I already tried to reinstall JDK, the Android Studio, the apk tools in the Unity Hub and i also reinstalled Unity itself (completely).

So, here is the most important Error:

CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed. 
D:/Unity/2019.2.3f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/Tools\OpenJDK\Windows\bin\java.exe -classpath "D:\Unity\2019.2.3f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\gradle\lib\gradle-launcher-5.1.1.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m" "assembleRelease"

stderr[

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':checkReleaseDuplicateClasses'.

  > 1 exception was raised by workers:
  >   java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate class com.unity3d.ads.BuildConfig found in modules classes.jar (:UnityAds:) and classes.jar (:unity-ads:)
  >   Duplicate class com.unity3d.ads.IUnityAdsListener found in modules classes.jar (:UnityAds:) and classes.jar (:unity-ads:)
  >   Duplicate class com.unity3d.ads.UnityAds found in modules classes.jar (:UnityAds:) and classes.jar (:unity-ads:)
  >   Duplicate class com.unity3d.ads.UnityAds$FinishState found in modules classes.jar (:UnityAds:) and classes.jar (:unity-ads:)
  >   Duplicate class com.unity3d.ads.UnityAds$PlacementState found in modules classes.jar (:UnityAds:) and classes.jar (:unity-ads:)
  >   Duplicate class com.unity3d.ads.UnityAds$UnityAdsError found in modules classes.jar (:UnityAds:) and classes.jar (:unity-ads:)
  >   Duplicate class com.unity3d.ads.mediation.IUnityAdsExtendedListener found in modules classes.jar (:UnityAds:) and classes.jar (:unity-ads:)
  >   Duplicate class com.unity3d.ads.metadata.InAppPurchaseMetaData found in modules classes.jar (:UnityAds:) and classes.jar (:unity-ads:)
  >   Duplicate class com.unity3d.ads.metadata.MediationMetaData found in modules classes.jar (:UnityAds:) and classes.jar (:unity-ads:)
  >   Duplicate class com.unity3d.ads.metadata.MetaData found in modules classes.jar (:UnityAds:) and classes.jar (:unity-ads:)
  >   Duplicate class com.unity3d.ads.metadata.PlayerMetaData found in modules classes.jar (:UnityAds:) and classes.jar (:unity-ads:)

  Go to the documentation to learn how to Fix dependency resolution errors.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 14s
]
stdout[

> Task :preBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
>   Task :compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
>   Task :checkReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :javaPreCompileRelease UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :mainApkListPersistenceRelease UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :createReleaseCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :processReleaseManifest
>   Task :processReleaseResources
>   Task :compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :compileReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :lintVitalRelease
>   Task :mergeReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :compileReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :mergeReleaseAssets
>   Task :validateSigningRelease UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :signingConfigWriterRelease UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :checkReleaseDuplicateClasses FAILED

Comment: Could you show your "Assets->Plugins->Android" folder? It looks like you have two android libraries(UnityAds and unity-ads) which contain the same classes.

Comment: Of course but i actually don't find this folder...

Comment: Could describe where i can find the folder?

Comment: Just try to find assets which are called "UnityAds" and "unity-ads" in your project

Comment: Oh alright... I just found a "UnityAds" folder and also just "UnityAds" files... No "unity-ads" files or folders....

Answer (score 6):

I fixed it by going to Assets > Play Services Resolver > Android Resolver > Delete Resolved Libraries

Answer (score 3):

I fixed it by going to Assets > External Dependency Manager > Android Resolver > Delete Resolved Libraries

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. I found I had enabled the built-in ads extensions option in the ads section of services alongside also having the ads package installed. Uninstalling the ads package in the package manager did the job for me

Answer (score 1):

it happened to me and I just solve it by commenting-out the unity-ads on gradle dependencies just like that:

```
    //implementation(name: 'unity-ads', ext:'aar')
```

Answer (score 0):

I just solved it, basically, the error started when I added the ads Assets from the assets store.
what I didn't know that I Had one installed from the package manager there for it was duplicate
what you should do is to delete the package from the package manager, because if you delete the folders that were downloaded from the asset store you can't implement the listener in your script.

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed that issue by deleting the **playcore.arr** file from the **Assets/GooglePlayPlugins/com.google.play.core/Runtime/Plugins** folder

[image]